# Cannot crop touched location with CGImageCreateWithImageInRect in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, crop

I am trying to copy a portion of the background image at the touch location, then add a subview in the same spot with the cropped portion. If I was doing this correctly, both images would line up and you couldn't tell two UIImageViews were there, but it ends up looking like the pics below. Why is this not lining up and why is the new image zoomed in a bit?

Update: My ImageView is the same size as the main view and the image mode is aspect fit, so the white above and below the image is still part of the imageview.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!.locationInView(view)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: touch, size: CGSize(width: 90, height: 90))

    let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(mainImageView.image!.CGImage, rect)

    if imageRef != nil {
        let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

                let bgImage = UIImageView(image: newImage)
                bgImage.center = touch
                self.view.addSubview(bgImage)
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(bgImage)
            }
}
```

Before Touch:

[image: Before Touch]

After Touches:

[image: After Touches]

Comment: You can use UIImageView-GeometryConversion class to get correct touch point .. here is link 
https://github.com/nubbel/UIImageView-GeometryConversion

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know where I can find an example in swift, because I'm still not quite sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried:  

let convertedPoint = self.mainImageView.convertPoint(touch, toView: self.mainImageView)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: convertedPoint, size: CGSize(width: 90, height: 90))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first!.locationInView(view)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.bounds.size)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let crop = CGRectMake(touch.x - 45, touch.y - 45, 90, 90)
    let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(screenshot.CGImage, crop)

    if imageRef != nil {
        let newImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: mainImageView.image!.scale, orientation: mainImageView.image!.imageOrientation)

                let bgImage = UIImageView(image: newImage)
                bgImage.center = touch
                self.view.addSubview(bgImage)
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(bgImage)
            }
        }
    }

}
```